# Any idea why ** is used in this case

Tags: c++, direct2d

Any idea why ** is used in this case?

```
HRESULT CreateSolidColorBrush(
  const D2D1_COLOR_F & color,
  ID2D1SolidColorBrush** solidColorBrush
);
```

The above is from Microsoft documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1rendertarget-createsolidcolorbrush(constd2d1_color_f__id2d1solidcolorbrush)

What is the benefit of using a pointer to a pointer in this case?

(Why didn't they develop the function that just returned ID2D1SolidColorBrush*)

Comment: *"Why didn't they develop the function that just returned ID2D1SolidColorBrush*"* - because returning HRESULT is one of the COM fundamentals.

Comment: It creates a new interface pointer, requires passing the pointer variable by reference.  Ideally it would look like ID2D1SolidColorBrush* CreateSolidColorBrush(
  const D2D1_COLOR_F & color) but it needs to return adequate error info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. What is the benefit of using a pointer to a pointer in this case?**

Because that function is probably intented to modify a pointer you may pass giving its address.

> When this method returns, contains the address of a pointer to the new
>   brush. This parameter is passed uninitialized.

It may have been declared as reference to pointer, but it is more clear to user that he must give the address of the pointer to be modified, as it will enforce him the semantic.

**2. Why didn't they develop the function that just returned `ID2D1SolidColorBrush*`?**

Because the function already returns something that is a status.

> If this method succeeds, it returns `S_OK`. Otherwise, it returns an
>   `HRESULT` error code.

Separating status and computed value is a good practice.

Comment: I don't understand your answer, a pointer can be modified, why a pointer to a pointer? - second part when I said returned I meant via a pointer (rather that a pointer to a pointer)

Comment: If you pass a pointer, you pass its value, not the pointer itself, thus if you want a function to modify one of its argument, the argument must be passed either by address or by reference.

Comment: I get pass by reference. Example: the standard strcpy(char* destination, const char* source). It does not need char** destination to copy the string.  What's the need for the extra pointer?

Comment: the pointers aren't changed by `strcpy`, it only changes the chars themselves. by contrast, `CreateSolidColorBrush` isn't changing a brush object that is already there, its changing the pointer itself to point to the brush it creates, therefore the pointer must be passed by reference (via a pointer to it) in order to change it

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Thanks for your patience in explaining this to me @kmdreko.